# How to create hover effect similar to the one on App Icon on Google's Homepage?

Tags: css, hover, effects, mousehover

I'm still new and learning HTML & CSS and while cloning Google Homepage I've done everything but unable to achieve this hover effect on App Icon.

[See the Picture if you are not sure what App Icon i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16kYC.png)

Comment: you can use the hover selector to change the background-color and border-radius https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `hover` effect is in this element `<a class="gb_A" aria-label="Google apps"...>`  and it is adding an effect of `"background-color: rgba(60,64,67,0.08)"`.

For adding this effect please create a rule as below:

```
a.gb_A:hover {
  background-color: rgba(60,64,67,0.08);
}
```